# Convert Over-Lapping Date Ranges To Rows of Date Ranges

Tags: t-sql, datetime

I have a list of Date Ranges in a table that can be open ended (enddate = null):

```
Index   startdate   enddate
1       2018-07-13  NULL
2       2018-11-14  2018-11-16
3       2018-11-15  2018-11-15
```

Query for Test Data:

```
DECLARE @ScheduleTable Table([Index] int not null, StartDate DateTime not null, EndDate DateTime null)
insert into @ScheduleTable ([Index], StartDate, EndDate)
values
(1,'2018-07-13',null)
, (2,'2018-11-14','2018-11-16')
, (3,'2018-11-15','2018-11-15')
select*from @ScheduleTable
```

How can I write a query that will "fill in the holes" and return the following results:

```
Index   startdate   enddate
1       2018-07-13  2018-11-13
2       2018-11-14  2018-11-14
3       2018-11-15  2018-11-15
2       2018-11-16  2018-11-16
1       2018-11-17  NULL
```

Query displaying expected results:

```
select 
1 as [Index], '2018-07-13' as StartDate, '2018-11-13' as EndDate
UNION ALL
select 
2 as [Index], '2018-11-14', '2018-11-14'
UNION ALL
select 
3 as [Index], '2018-11-15', '2018-11-15'
UNION ALL
select 
2 as [Index], '2018-11-16', '2018-11-16'
UNION ALL
select 
1 as [Index], '2018-11-17', null
```

I'd prefer an answer that doesn't involve parameters/ temp table etc. I have a Date Dimension table if that would help.

In the above example, the entry with Index=1 is open-ended and starts on 7.13. It is interrupted by Index=2 on 11.14. Index=2 is then interrupted by Index=3 on 11.15. Index=2 then starts again on 11.16. Followed by Index=1 starting up again on 11.17
The Index determines the order of preference, so Index=2 will override Index=1 on 11.14 - 11.16 and Index=3 will override Index=2 on 11.15.
Here is my current query using lead():

```
DECLARE @MinDate DateTime = '2015-01-01'
DECLARE @MaxDate DateTime = '2020-01-01'

select
row_number() over(partition by dealid order by ss.StartDate, ss.id) as [Index]
, ss.startdate
, ss.enddate
, case when ss.enddate is null then
    dateadd(d,-1,lead(ss.startdate,1,@MaxDate) over(partition by dealid order by ss.startdate, ss.id)) 
    else ss.enddate end
    as EndDate
from
[dbo].[Schedule]ss
where ss.enabled = 1
```

Comment: What's the logic between sample data and expect result?

Comment: Can the date ranges overlap? If yes, what should be returned if they do?

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Can you have more than one record with `null` as `endDate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem using the following:

Steps:

- Obtain table of Dates from DateDimension table
- Join schedules to DateDimension table
- row_number the schedules to determine which one takes precedence for a given date
- rank results, order by date
- dense_rank results, partition by schedule Id, order by date
- subtract the dense_rank results from the rank results to create a unique Id for each group of contiguous dates
- Obtain the min and max date for each range of dates

Query to populate test data:

```
DECLARE @ScheduleTable Table([Index] int not null, StartDate DateTime not null, EndDate DateTime null)
insert into @ScheduleTable ([Index], StartDate, EndDate)
values
(1,'2018-07-13',null)
, (2,'2018-11-14','2018-11-16')
, (3,'2018-11-15','2018-11-15')
```

Solution:

```
DECLARE @MinDate Date = dateadd(year,-2,getdate())
DECLARE @MaxDate DateTime = dateadd(year,2,getdate())

select 
min(dt) as StartDate
, max(dt) as EndDate
, dense_rank() over(Order by [Index]) [Index]
from
(
select
--Create "groups" using a raw Rank minus dense_rank, partitioned by [Index]
rank() over(order by dt) - dense_rank() over(partition by [Index] order by dt) qlt,
[Index], dt
from
(
select
--Apply row_number to identify which schedule takes precedence on a given day
--Index=2 takes precedence over Index=1
row_number() over(partition by inr.[date] order by ss.[Index] desc) rm,
[date] dt
, ss.*
from
(
    --Obtain Table of Dates from DateDimension table
    select
    [date]
    from
    [dbo].[DateDimension]dd
    where dd.[date] >= @MinDate
    and dd.[date] <= @MaxDate
)inr
    --join schedules to DateDimension table
    left join 
    (
        select *
        from
        @ScheduleTable
    )ss
        on ss.StartDate <= inr.[date]
        and (ss.enddate >= inr.[date]
            or ss.enddate is null)

)inr2
--Exclude any Schedule that is not row_number=1
where inr2.rm = 1
and inr2.[Index] is not null
)inr3
--Group on Index first then Rank minus dense_rank, partitioned by [Index]
group by [Index], qlt
order by StartDate
, [Index]
```

Results:

```
StartDate   EndDate     Index
2018-07-13  2018-11-13  1
2018-11-14  2018-11-14  2
2018-11-15  2018-11-15  3
2018-11-16  2018-11-16  2
2018-11-17  2020-11-12  1
```